# TYPO3 ver. 6.2.1 ImageMagick scaling issue

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have a little problem getting ImageMagick to work in TYPO3 ver. 6.2.1.
[image: error messages]

I have added the right path for the `im_path`, because when I make a test.php file with the code

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system("/usr/local/bin/convert");
```

and run the file, I get a page with a lot of test info. If I change the path to `/usr/bin/`, I get a blank page.

So I know the path is `/usr/local/bin/convert`, but I still get the error in the image when I test the Scaling function.

Does anyone know what the issue is with TYPO3 ver. 6.2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the path in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php
It can be that the path itself is not updated in the LocalConfiguration file.

Comment: its not writing any info to that file. I have only this GFX code.
 'GFX' => array(
  'im_mask_temp_ext_gif' => 1,
  'jpg_quality' => '80',
 ),

Comment: You can edit your localconfig file yourself manually :

'GFX' => array(
'colorspace' => 'sRGB',
'im' => 1,
  'im_mask_temp_ext_gif' => 1,
  'im_path' => '/opt/local/bin/',
  'im_path_lzw' => '/opt/local/bin/',
  'im_v5effects' => 1,
  'im_version_5' => 'im6',
  'image_processing' => 1,
  'jpg_quality' => '80',
 ),